# .NET Core: Order of optional parameters in GET request

Tags: c#, rest, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET Core REST api, and I am requested to handle a GET request where the route template of optional parameter should be like `…/parameterName/parameterValue/...`.

What I've tried so far is something like this:

```
[HttpGet("{manatoryParam1}/{manatoryParam2}/{manatoryParam3}/optionalParamName1/{optionalParamName1?}/optionalParamName2/{optionalParamName2?}")]
public ActionResult Get(string manatoryParam1, string manatoryParam2, string optionalParamName1, int optionalParamName2)
```

But I have two issues:

1. How can I escape the first optional parameter, because when I make the following request: `url/value1/value2/optionalParamName1//optionalParamName2/value` I get 404 error
2. What if I have a long list of optional parameters, and I want the last optional parameter only, should I enter all the previous optional parameters, or is there a another way to enter only the needed paramaters?

Comment: This looks like a POST request would be much easier to manage, are you sure you need it to be a GET?

Comment: That looks like way too many parameters to include in the route. Why don't you use query parameters?

Comment: Query parameters should do the trick. Also, how about setting the default values for the optional parameters in your method!

Comment: @DavidG, I wish I could use a POST request,

Comment: `[FromUri]` seems like an option here. Create the class with properties that you expect and pass it like an object. FromUri will model it as query params.

Comment: `Queries are not an option unfortunately` Why not?

Comment: @mjwills: company conventions

Comment: Chat with the person who oversees those conventions. Querystring is **tailor made** for long lists of optional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong for so many reasons. The best method for dealing with this is to create a class with the properties in that you want to pass, and then perform some logic to extract the values on the server side. Like so:

```
public class QueryParameters
{
    public string manatoryParam1 {get; set;}
    public string manatoryParam2 {get; set;}
    public string optionalParamName1 {get; set;}
    public int optionalParamName2 {get; set;}
}
```

And then your controller will look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get(QueryParameters query)
```

Note: You should be returning IActionResult too - it helps with unit tests ;-)